# While loop testing equality with 0 will not break

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

This while loop won't end. Any suggestions for this Python program?

[Edit: Upon request I quoted the entire program. It's supposed to find the largest palindrome produced by two n digit decimals.]

```
def palindrome(n):

    first = 1
    second = 1

    largestPalindrome = 1

    palindrome = True

    while(first < 10**n):
        while(second < 10**n):

            number = []
            candidate = 1
            while candidate!=0:
                number.append(candidate%10)
                candidate = candidate // 10
                print("in") 

            i = 0
            ub = len(number)//2
            while(i<ub):
                if(number[i]!=number[len(number)-1-i]):
                   palindrome = False
                i += 1

            if palindrome == True:
                largestPalindrome = first*second

    print(largestPalindrome)
```

Comment: There is no reason at all why it would loop forever, it is 0 after the first `//` bar you have `candidate = candidate // 10` actually outside the loop

Comment: Is `number` a predefined identifier that's being shadowed, perhaps?

Comment: @TomZych, number has nothing to do with the while loop.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps it's a parent class of `int` or something.

Comment: Are you sure it's this loop that's stuck, and not an enclosing loop?

Comment: @Unprecedented, add the surrounding code

Comment: Please add in your loop : print candidate

Comment: When I execute this code (python 3.4) it exists on the first loop.

Comment: I added the entire code.

Comment: `first` and `second` are never incremented.

Comment: Oh, wow. You got it brunodea.

Comment: @brunodea, you should have added it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Your external `while` loops

```
while(first < 10**n):
    while(second < 10**n):
       ...
```

are checking if the variables `first` and `second` are under a certain value (`10**n`). The problem is that, inside these loops, **you never increment either `first` or `second`**, so the condition is always satisfied and your loops keep going on forever.